# Add gdb build-id section to existing binary

Tags: debugging, gcc, gdb, debug-symbols, openwrt

I have some openwrt rootfs images built with debug symbols and want to strip the symbols to separate files to fit on a device, but also allow gdb to load the symbols automatically from a folder that has symbols for each build-id.

The openwrt build system doesn't add `-Wl,--build-id` to gcc commands. Is there a way to add these build-ids afterwards, the way `objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink` works ? Or to append the -Wl option to every openwrt link command ?

Adding the section by hand works but the build-id note is byte aligned whereas ld aligns it at 4 bytes:

```
# see https://www.technovelty.org/code/separate-debug-info.html

add-build-id() 
{
    local sha1="$1"
    local exename="$2"

    local tmp=`mktemp --suffix=build-id`

    if readelf --file-header $exename | grep "big endian" > /dev/null; then
        echo -en "\x00\x00\x00\x04" >> $tmp # name_size
        echo -en "\x00\x00\x00\x14" >> $tmp # hash_size
        echo -en "\x00\x00\x00\x03" >> $tmp # NT_GNU_BUILD_ID
    elif readelf --file-header $exename | grep "little endian" > /dev/null; then
        echo -en "\x04\x00\x00\x00" >> $tmp # name_size
        echo -en "\x14\x00\x00\x00" >> $tmp # hash_size
        echo -en "\x03\x00\x00\x00" >> $tmp # NT_GNU_BUILD_ID
    else
        echo >&2 "Could not determine endianness for: $exename"
        return 1
    fi

    echo -en "GNU\x00" >> $tmp # GNU\0
    echo $sha1 | xxd -ps -r >> $tmp

    objcopy --add-section .note.gnu.build-id=$tmp $exename
    rm $tmp
}

add-build-id `sha1sum "$1"` "$1"
```